# How to make a cooldown for each command Discord JS

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**I had a problem that when you use one command and want to use another, the cooldown remains, although it is a different command. In short, I have one cooldown for all teams, I want to fix this

This my code:
**

```
    
    if (command === 'ферма1') {
       const cooldown = used.get(message.author.id);
        if (cooldown) {
          const remaining = Duration(cooldown - Date.now(), {units: ["m", "s"], round: true});
          message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(`Осталось ждать ${remaining}`)
                .setColor(0x0099FF)]})
            
              
          }
        else{
        const roles = message.member.roles.cache
        if (!roles.some((role) => role.name === 'Плохая ферма'))
        return message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription('У тебя нет плохой фермы.')
                .setColor(0x0099FF)],
            
        });
        
        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription('Ты получил 30000 евро за слабую ферму.')
                .setColor(0x0099FF)],
        })
        unb.editUserBalance(guildID, userID, { cash: +30000 });
        used.set(message.author.id, Date.now() +  3600000);
        setTimeout(() => used.delete(message.author.id), 3600000);
     }     
     
    }    
     if (command === 'ферма2') {
      const cooldown = used.get(message.author.id);
      if (cooldown) {
          const remaining = Duration(cooldown - Date.now(), {units: ["m", "s"], round: true});
          message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription(`Осталось ждать ${remaining}`)
                .setColor(0x0099FF)]})
      }
          else{
        const roles = message.member.roles.cache
        if (!roles.some((role) => role.name === 'Нормальная ферма'))
        return message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription('У тебя нет нормальной фермы.')
                .setColor(0x0099FF)],
        });
        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [new EmbedBuilder()
                .setDescription('Ты получил 50000 евро за нормальную ферму.')
                .setColor(0x0099FF)],
        })
        unb.editUserBalance(guildID, userID, { cash: +50000 });
        used.set(message.author.id, Date.now() +  3600000);
        setTimeout(() => used.delete(message.author.id), 3600000);
    }
     }  
     
    }   
)
client.login(token);
```

I tried to search on the Internet, but I did not understand

Answer (score 1):

So you have noticed your [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) has an affect on all commands you have, so you need a specific [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection)for each command.

In order to do this, you can create command specific collections within your main/larger **`cooldown`** collection. So **`cooldown`** has smaller collections within it, with the key as the command name - then within the smaller collections will contains the users for that command.

```js
/* Creating the main cooldown collection */
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

/* Create or fetch the specific command Collection */
if (!cooldowns.has('Command Name')) cooldowns.set('Command Name', new Collection());
const timestamps = cooldowns.get('Command Name');

/* If the user is in the cooldown timestamp collection */
if (timestamps.has('User Id')) return;


/* Set and remove the cooldown */
timestamps.set('User ID', Date.now());
setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete('User ID'), 'Timeout Amount in MS');
```

Comment: The timestamp map should not be initialized in the `messageCreate` event, because that will reset the map and not work accordingly. Make sure to initialize the collection outside of the message create event.

Comment: The **`cooldown`** collection should not be initialized within the MessageCreate event (I agree for the reason you've said). However as the `timestamps` is a collection within `cooldown`, and is checked for value (and set if needed) before the `const timestamps` it makes no difference.

Comment: Ooh, I meant `cooldowns` variable shouldn't be inside the event, the timestamps variable is just fine as it is. :) @ThatsLiamS